# Difference between objdump -r and -R switches

Tags: binary-analysis, objdump

`objdump` man page says,

```
-r
--reloc
      Print the relocation entries of the file.  If used with -d or -D,
      the relocations are printed interspersed with the disassembly.

-R
--dynamic-reloc
      Print the dynamic relocation entries of the file. This is only
      meaningful for dynamic objects, such as certain types of shared
      libraries. As for -r, if used with -d or -D, the relocations are
      printed interspersed with the disassembly.
```

Can anybody please explain how do these two options differ? What's the difference between relocation and dynamic relocation entries?

Answer (score 3):

### Ordinary object file

As the notes say, the `-R` is only meaningful for dynamic objects.  For ordinary `.o` files from simple programs, the `-r` will show the relocation entries.  As an example, this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("Hello, world!\");
}
```

We can produce an object file with this:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11   -c -o sample.o sample.c
```

Produces this output when we run the command `objdump -r sample.o`:

```
sample.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000005 R_X86_64_32       .rodata
000000000000000a R_X86_64_PC32     puts-0x0000000000000004


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
```

(This is an x86_64 Linux box.)

With `objdump -R sample.o` we get this:

```
objdump: sample.o: not a dynamic object
objdump: sample.o: Invalid operation
```

This is expected since this is not a shared library.

### Shared library

By contrast, we can use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int hello() {
    return puts("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

And create a library with this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -fPIC -shared -o libsample.so sample.c
```

Now the `-R` makes sense:

```
objdump -R libsample.so
```

Output:

```
libsample.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000200df8 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000000660
0000000000200e00 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000000620
0000000000200e10 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000200e10
0000000000200fd8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000200fe0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __gmon_start__
0000000000200fe8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000200ff0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000200ff8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000201018 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  puts@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

### Playing games

There are two other utilities: `readelf` and `elfedit` that allows us to look at and modify the binary in more detail.  If we create a shared object as shown above, but on a 32-bit Linux machine and then run `readelf -a libsample.so` the output is long, but starts with this:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x3f0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          5884 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 26
```

We can then play games such as changing the file to a EXEC type instead of a DYN type:

```
elfedit --output-type=EXEC test.so
```

Now if we rerun `readelf`, everything is the same except for that tag:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x3f0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          5884 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 26
```

Although the type has changed, it will still function as a shared library.

Comment: On this [binary](http://shell-storm.org/repo/CTF/PlaidCTF-2013/Pwnable/ropasaurusrex-200/ropasaurusrex-85a84f36f81e11f720b1cf5ea0d1fb0d5a603c0d) (not a shared object), `-r` doesn't work while `-R` works. How can you explain that?

Comment: I've added to my answer to show exactly how that's done.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic relocations are relocations applied by the dynamic linker (usually `ld.so` or equivalent), as opposed to the link editor (e.g. `ld`) for the object files' relocations. They are pointed to by the [dynamic section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3677/chapter6-42444/index.html)  entries such as `DT_REL`, `DT_RELA` and `DT_JMPREL`. The dynamic linker often supports only a limited set of relocations.
Not only shared objects but also dynamic (non-static) executables may have dynamic relocations. Unstripped binaries may also have remaining non-dynamic relocations but those are not used by the dynamic linker.